# How to make the search field of ngx-mat-intl-tel-input focusable?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

I am using ngx-mat-intl-tel-input for Angular 10, and am facing an issue with making the country search field focusable.

```
 <ngx-mat-intl-tel-input
  [enablePlaceholder]="true"
  [enableSearch]="true"
  name="phoneNumber">
</ngx-mat-intl-tel-input>
```

**Problem**: There is a search bar for country search, but it gets unfocused really quickly so if you type too slow, it doesn't pick up your input. After it unfocuses, it registers every character individually and goes to the country code with that letter.

**Example**: If you search for country "India", press the key "i" and if you wait for 2 seconds, it scrolls to the list from the point where countries with the letter "i" start, next if you type "n", it scrolls to countries with the letter "n", but it won't let you type "india" in one go.

**Stackblitz example** https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-mat-intl-tel-inpu-demo?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: can you provide the example code in https://stackblitz.com/ , when tried the same its works as expected not able to reproduce the issue

Comment: @a.prakash I have added the stackblitz link, the issue is reproducible for angular versions which are greater than 9.

Comment: @KanishkaLahori its defined by `ngx-mat-intl-tel-input` , You have to do some work around by your self in oder to do it right.